# What is the best way to add a vent over this door?

Tags: drywall, heating, air-conditioning, vent

I would like to add a vent above the door to my laundry room because it gets fairly warm in there when the door is left closed for any significant amount of time. All that's there is a single layer of drywall that I have punched through for other projects like running cables.

In my head, I'm picturing something like this, but everything I find online when I search for "drywall vent" or "air vent" seems geared towards hooking up to an HVAC duct which is not what I want.

[image: sample floor vent]

The space above the door is 8" x 32" and I would like to try and fill most of it with the vent. Here's the front and back view:
[image: Door front image] [image: door rear image]

Is there a product out there that would fit my needs and I simply am searching for the wrong terms? Or am I going about this the entirely wrong way?

Comment: Attaching to a duct or drywall does not make any difference.  They are made for ducts since that is what most people use them for.  Get one that is the right size for you.  Might also look for  grilles

Comment: Yeah, vent grill (or grille) is the typical term for that application.On the other hand, not having drywall on the face of the walls in there is somewhat of a fire risk, and the NM/B cables are not run in a code compliant manner. Or are those data/low voltage? Looks like 6x30 or two 8x16 are available.

Comment: adding one vent up high won't do much. Adding two vents, one high, one low, will do a lot.

Comment: They're ethernet cables

Comment: Keyword that may help you find/design what you want: "transom". Transom windows above doors were common when people were more dependent on natural light; many of them could be opened for flow-through ventilation. I don't know how high your ceilings are, but this remains a nice design detail.

Comment: @dandavis, if there's enough of a temperature gradient to induce convection the typical ~1" gap under the door should suffice.

Comment: I had an office many years ago with a vent/grille in the bottom of two of the doors. Burglars smashed through it, opened the door and stole stuff. Police came, etc. No response from landlord. So I went to the local hardware store and got some plywood - one piece for front of door, one for back, some big bolts through the corners. Moved to a different office building when the lease was up. Years later stopped by - the only thing the landlord did was paint my plywood.

Comment: Also. It's common to just put louvered doors on laundry closets.

Comment: @isherwood ... and if there isn't such a gap (it's more like 1/4" under most of my doors, maybe 1/2" for some, just cut a hole in the bottom of the door and fit another grille (on both side, then the hole doesn't have to be very tidy.  If you have hollow doors and are feeling fancy you might want to line the hole; you may even be able to do it with plastic duct sized to match the grilles (availability depending on location of course)

Comment: Similar to keshlam's comment, I'm seeing relevant results when I look up "transfer grille".  "Transfer duct" is often what you would call ductwork serving that purpose, so I figured that terminology might get results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Common HVAC grilles are routinely installed directly to framing (or even drywall, with hollow wall anchors). Cold air returns are traditionally just framing voids. This situation is really no different. (The one in your photo is probably mounted this way--they don't actually connect to the duct except where the mounting screws happen to hit a flange.)

Pick one up that suits your needs (closeable or not and in the size you prefer), then cut a hole to the size of the vented area. Take the time to level and center it well. Float some scrap lumber behind the screw holes if there's none there and screw it on. Easy peasy.

Note that high return grilles are often installed with the slats oriented upward so that from below there's less of a visual black hole effect.

Answer (score 2):

Don't.  Buy a same-size and same handedness door with the vent built in. Remount the hinges and you are done.

Comment: That sounds rather expensive. And finding door slabs with perfectly positioned hinges is not always as easy as it sounds. Of course, you'd have to reinstall the latch hardware, too.

Comment: @gbronner, So you're suggesting spending , say $300 instead of buying a $10 grill?

Comment: $10 grill, plus a lot of effort to make it look nice, and venting all the steam from the bathroom into the wall behind the sheetrock. I could be wrong, but that door looks like a thin-shell printed to resemble a 5 panel.